# Function returning two values, store one value in variable and add the other to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function `filters` that returns two values. I want to store one in a variable `data` and the other is a string I want to append to the variable `filter`.

I know the following not possible, but it is basically what I want:

```
IN: 
filter = "Hello "
data=, filter+= filters(arg, arg, arg)

OUT: 
data = *an array that filters return)
filter = "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary value to get the second value (string) and then append it to the `filter` variable.

**Note**: You should **not** use `filter` as variable name because it's one of Python's reserved keywords.

```
myFilter = "Hello "
data, val = filters(arg, arg, arg)
myFilter += val
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here I have a function that returns two variables:

```
def myFunc():
    return 1, 2
```

All I have to do to access these variables is this:

```
var1, var2 = myFunc()
```

Now, `var1 = 1` and `var2 = 2`

Comment: I think the important part of the question is the OP wants to use `+=` in the assignment of the second value (`var2` in your example).

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the 2 values to their respective variables first before doing operations on them.

```
def return_two():
    return [1,2,3], 'World'

filter = "Hello "
data, sub_string = return_two()

print(data) # [1,2,3]
print(filter + sub_string) # Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc():
    return "123","World"

var1 = ""
var2 = "Hello "
var1 = myfunc()[0]
var2 += myfunc()[1]

print var1, var2
```

Output:123 Hello World